# How use file to set RewriteCond filter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need redirect request with referer in list domains

Now I write:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain1\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain2\.com
```

I need use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} <filenametxt>?????
```

domain1.com
domain2.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "txt" RewriteMap, but you'd need to restructure quite a bit.  You'd need to lookup just the domain from the referrer and make sure you get back any key.

Your input would be e.g.

```
domain1.com dummy-value
domain2.com dummy-value
...
```